# How do I convert these 2 columns as seen below in In [10] to a dataframe/table to be able to export to a csv file

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, export

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8H1mZ.png)

Hi, I am very new to Python and I plan to create a final exportable table with these reviews scraped from a website to see the words that were most used. I have thus managed to get this 2 columns but have no idea how to proceed, can I directly export this into a table in excel or must I convert it into a dataframe then export it to a CSV? And what is the required code to run as such? Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

It's convenient to use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) library for working with dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

series = pd.Series(wordcount)
series.to_csv("wordcount.csv")
```

However, if you use the code above, you'll get a warning. To fix it, there are 2 ways:

1) Add `header` parameter:

```
series.to_csv("wordcount.csv", header=True)
```

2) Or convert series to dataframe and then save it (without new index):

```
df = series.reset_index()
df.to_csv("wordcount.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your help. I have inputed the code as you mentioned but a error message has appeared when applying the code: series.to_csv("wordcount.csv")

Error: //anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: FutureWarning: The signature of `Series.to_csv` was aligned to that of `DataFrame.to_csv`, and argument 'header' will change its default value from False to True: please pass an explicit value to suppress this warning.
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

How do I verify this?

Comment: @LukasPhuah It's not an error, it's just a warning. I've added ways to fix it in the answer